# Query MongoDB with morphia by element on String list

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

This is the documents format:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("123")
 "types" : [ "PHONE", "ADDRESS" ]
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("345")
 "types" : [ "PHONE" ]
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("567")
 "types" : [ "PHONE", "NAME" ]
}
```

And this is the query to find elements which contains certain types:

```
public List<MyCollection> findByType(Type type) {
  return getDatastore().createQuery(MyCollection.class)
     .field("types").hasThisElement(type.toString())
     .asList();
}
```

With this code, I get this error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $elemMatch needs an Object
```

I tried using `hasThisOne` method, but always returns an empty array.

How can I do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a `type.toString()`?

I'd assume you have a `List<Type> types` in your entity, right? Then the query should use the enum as well and not its string representation.

And you can probably use:

```
getDatastore().createQuery(MyCollection.class)
   .field("types").equal(type).asList();
```

Yes, even for arrays.